# Combobox binding and updating other property

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have following XAML inside data grid:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="3">
    <Setter TargetName="content" Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox 
                    SelectedValue="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding List, Converter={Converters:DelimitedListToItemsSource}}">
                </ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

What it does - when "`Type = 3`" - cell displays `ComboBox`.
Than I parse "List" property inside my DelimitedListToItemsSource converter
List looks like "`Value 1|0|Value 2|1|Value 3|3`" - basically key/value array in delimited string.

What I want to do is to bind SelectedValue to "value" part of of my delimited string.

I think I need to write another value converter for `ItemsSource` but I don't know how to get "`List`" property passed in there? It binds to "Value" property

So, I guess question boils down to passing object reference into value converter so I can set actual converted value based on other data in object..

And, if you read whole question and I'm doing it wrong alltogether - I welcome suggestions..

Comment: What sort of object is your Converter returning?

Comment: Converter returns simple String[] I throw away every second value from delimited string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass more than one bound value to a regular Converter.

You can either setup a MultiConverter which takes two parameters (SelectedValue and ValueList) and returns the correct item, or change your Converter so it returns a list of Key/Value pairs and bind your ComboBox's `SelectedValuePath="Key"` and `DisplayMemberPath="Value"`